# Using auto in loop error "auto must have an initializer"

Tags: c++, auto

I want to use the **auto** keyword but get this error when compiling (Visual C++ Express 2010)

```
typedef std::list<int> MyList;

int main()
{
    const int args[] = {0, 1, 2};
    MyList myList(std::begin(args), std::end(args));

    for(auto& value : myList) 
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':'
error C2530: 'value' : references must be initialized
error C3531: 'value': a symbol whose type contains 'auto' must have an initializer
```

Comment: Given that VS2013 doesn't fully support C++11, I have much less hope for 2010.

Comment: VS2010 supports `auto`, but does not support range-for loops. VS2013 does though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ compiler in VS2010 does support range-based for loops, but with [a pre-standard syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177203(v=vs.100).aspx).
(And seriously, you can't expect a compiler finished about 2 years before the Standard to be fully compliant)

```
for each (int& value in myList) 
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int &', you should replace with: for each(const int& value in myList). Btw, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in your code:

1. You need to explicitly include the headers for the functionality you use.

   ```
   #include <list>
   #include <iostream>
   ```
2. VS2010 does not support C++11 range-based "for" loops. The feature was implemented much later. See the following table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx